# KnockoutJs : Observable array not updating view with latest model data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Basically issue is when I click on link it show initially e.g 2 records on view . But when I close page and click on link again it suppose to show me updated records from model as I am giving call to controller method which intern to return Json resultData. but it's not working like that it just append View list to itself and displays view with 4 records. if I do repeatedly open window it shows records like 2,4,8,16.... :(

My code is something like below  :

**File1.cshtml  :**

```
<div id="Section1">
    <div>
        <span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: OnClick">Click here</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**File1.js :**

```
var Section1VM = {
    OnClick: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/controller/View/',
            success: function (resultData) {
                initSection2VM(resultData);  function declared in File2.js
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
};
Ko.applybinding (Section1VM , document.getElementById("Section1"))
```

**File2.js**

```
function initSection2VM(resultData) {
    var counter = 0
    var Section2VM = {
        List: ko.observableArray([]),
        ListCount:ko.observable()
    };
    Section2VM.List([]);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(resultData, function (entry) {
        Section2VM.List.push(entry);
        counter++;
    });
    Section2VM.ListCount(counter);
    ko.applyBindings(Section2VM , document.getElementById("Section2"));
};
```

File2.cshtml

```
<div class="whiteContent" id="Section2">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: List()">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: SomeDate"></span></td>
            <td><span><a href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: SomeLink }, text: SomeNumber">   
            </a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

**Code description :**

1. On click of “click here” link will give call to “OnClick” which is in File1.js
2. “OnClick” will give ajax call to get updated list from controller. Controller return Json result to function.
3. On success of  “OnClick” will give call to initSection2VM(resultData); which is declared in File2.js and pass Json resultdata.
4. Pushing resultData to Section2VM.List and then ko.applyBindings(Section2VM , document.getElementById("Section2"));
5. MeesageCenterPopUpSection is loading in file2.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve above issue. Actually the problem was I unnecessary binding KO code in function. below code changes I have made.

```
    $(function () { // docuement.ready function. 
        ko.applyBindings(Section2VM, document.getElementById("Section2"));
    });
    //Define globally 
    var Section2VM= {
        List: ko.observableArray([]),
        ListCount: ko.observable()
    };

    function initSection2VM (resultData) {
        var counter = 0
        Section2VM.List([]);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(resultData, function (entry) {
            Section2VM.List.push(entry);
            counter++;
        });
        Section2VM.ListCount(counter);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you invoke `ko.applyBindings` too many times. See, this method, when called, *links* some Observable object with the DOM node that should represent it. And each time when this Observable object is updated, its DOM representation also updates itself - that's what `observable` means, after all. Calling `ko.applyBindings` to *update* the representation is just wrong - while in [some cases](http://jsfiddle.net/QNsWx/) Knockout manages to fix the situation itself, in [others](http://jsfiddle.net/4ShBA/) it's just helpless.

Going from theory to practice, the easiest way to fix your problem is this:

```
var initSection2VM = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var Section2VM = {
        List: ko.observableArray([]),
        ListCount:ko.observable()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(Section2VM, document.getElementById("Section2"));    
    return function(resultData) {
        Section2VM.List([]);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(resultData, function (entry) {
            Section2VM.List.push(entry);
            counter++;
        });
        Section2VM.ListCount(counter);
    }
})();
```

Here I localized `Section2VM` definition and invoked `applyBindings` immedidately. The resulting function will be able work with it, but to the external world it will be invisible.

And here's a [simplified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtf5G/) to show this in action.

---

The alternative approach would be rewriting the function itself after the first call:

```
function initSection2VM(resultData) {
    var counter = 0;
    var Section2VM = {
        List: ko.observableArray([]),
        ListCount:ko.observable()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(Section2VM, document.getElementById("Section2"));
    initSection2VM = function(resultData) {
        Section2VM.List([]);
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(resultData, function (entry) {
            Section2VM.List.push(entry);
            counter++;
        });
        Section2VM.ListCount(counter);
    };
    initSection2VM(resultData);
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ntHjW/).

Comment: Thanks for reply !it still not work. in file1.js calling function of File2.js gives reference error.var Section1VM = { OnClick: function () { $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: '/controller/View/', success: function (resultData) { initSection2VM(resultData); }, dataType: 'json' }); } }; Ko.applybinding (Section1VM , document.getElementById("Section1")) it give below error on browser console:ReferenceError: initSection2VM is not defined[Break On This Error] initSection2VM(resultData);

Comment: Sigh... ok, does the approach in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BaqPC/) suit you?

Comment: Approach in demo at least resolved referencing issue which I mention above. but it's going in recursion it's not coming of of function..

Comment: How come it doesn't endless loop in the demo then? Did you copy the code as is?

Comment: yes I copy code as is.. I did not made any changes other than variable names

Comment: Can you show your code then, in `pastebin` or something like that? The only possible reason is that you don't redefine the function `initSection2VM` before calling it within its first implementation (with `initSection2VM(resultData)`) line.

Comment: Thanks for your replies it got resolved. Below are code changes I have made: I Removed Ko binding from initSection2VM(resultData) function and added document ready function. $(function(){
ko.applyBindings(Section2VM,document.getElementById("Section2"));
});var Section2VM = {List: ko.observableArray([]),ListCount: ko.observable()};function initSection2VM(resultData){var counter = 0
Section2VM.List([]);ko.utils.arrayForEach(resultData, function (entry) {
Section2VM.List.push(entry);counter++;
});Section2VM.ListCount(counter);};